# As an outsourced employee, is it reasonable to ask for benefits that regular employees have on business trips?

Tags: salary, contractors, contracting, benefits, outsourcing

I work for company A. My company outsources 10-15 people (including myself) to company B. I go to a business trip to a foreign country as the only person from company A (there are a few people from company B with me). Company B is covering my business trip expenses (flights, transport, allowance, hotel). I'm the only person from company A to go for a business trip abroad while working for company B.

Upon arrival, I learn that company B has a policy that doubles their employees salary for the time of a business trip in a foreign country. I'm not included because I'm not an employee of that company.

The fact that I have no said benefits saddened me, as I do exactly the same job as my colleagues and I'm not getting any the extras. The country I'm staying in for my bunsiness trip is much more expensive than my home country. People from company B can afford going the gym, restaurants etc because of the benefits, and I cannot.

I've previously agreed formally to be on the business trip to the end of the year and verbally/semi-formally (nothing in terms of flights/hotels has been arranged yet, and I can work remotely) to continue it in the new year.

Is it reasonable to ask in my company (A), after this first part of my business trip has ended, whether or not company B can extend their business trip benefits policy to contractors? 
How about stating that I don't want to go back abroad if I don't get the same benefits as employees of company B get (I don't mind if they say no).

Comment: How long will you be in this remote location?  Business trip often connotes a short visit (up to a couple weeks) while your description makes this look you it may be longer.  Reasonable request may vary based on how long you will be there, visiting vs living there for a while.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it's not a reasonable expectation. You don't work for Company B and they are providing you with flights, transport, allowance, hotel and expecting you to work, not go to gym, or restaurants. Anything more than that is not their concern. Specifically anything their employees get is also not your concern.

If you have any reason for wanting more money at such a time. Company A is the place to ask. Company B is already taking care of basic extra expenses.

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic problem, and is why companies keep salaries/benefits/etc private from employee to employee.

You were happy with your working arrangement, and willing to do it. You're only upset because you now realize that other people are doing the same job for more. The company likely specifically outsourced the job you now hold because it is cheaper than if they do that themselves. Considering that, it's unlikely they will say yes.

As you had already agreed upon the terms of the position, you don't have much of a leg to stand on if you make the demand either. You're almost definitely being paid less than the full-time employees. Are you going to demand a raise as well?

In short, no, it is not reasonable to make such a demand.

Answer (score 1):

Be *very* careful you're not falling into a "Grass is greener" mindset here.  If you're happy with Company A, don't let the fact that *other* people elsewhere in the world have a perk that you don't get you down.  If it helps, think of it this way: if Company A outsourced you to Company C - a miserable place where the salary was below average, the workweek was 6 days long, and there were no medical benefits or days off... would you want Company A to jettison what they were going to provide for you to give you Company C's perks instead?

Company A pays your salary and is responsible for your employment - you work for them, not Company B.

Answer (score 1):

There are three separate issues here, only one of which is actually relevant to you:

1. The business trip expenses that B covers.
2. The double salary B provides their employees.
3. The spending habits of B's employees.

Before approaching your company you need to ask yourself:

Is the money that B provides for business expenses sufficient to cover all the necessary costs of the business trip?

If it is not, you need to communicate to your company that B is not covering all the costs of the business trip and work out an arrangement so that all the costs are covered on future trips.

As for the double salary for B's employees and their spending habits, that does not concern you or your employer.  You are not an employee of B, so even if you do the same work you are not entitled to the same benefits.  And if B's employees choose to overspend on business trips that doesn't mean that you need to do the same.